# How to make a 2D grid of images?

Tags: android, xml

I am new to Android development and I am trying to make an app that will have a menu made of a 3x3 grid of images. I am having trouble getting the images to scale and take up 1/3rd of the screen width each. I think I should use `RelativeLayout`, but I doesn't seem to support `android:weight`. I then tried `LinearLayout`, but it only scaled horizontally.

I've been working on this all day and haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

*EDIT: I found a way that works, using `TableLayout` with `android:shrinkColumns="*"` for width, and adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to all `TableRows` for height. I used `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`. but the scale type was not the problem, getting the View to fit was. This method works for images that are too large, but it might would not work for images that are too small. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Get the Screen device Height and Width
2nd Scale your image to the one third value of the image and re assign it

Check this code

The Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the MainActivity.java file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView img[] = new ImageView[9];
    img[0] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img[1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    img[2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    img[3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    img[4] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    img[5] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    img[6] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
    img[7] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
    img[8] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView9);


    Display mDisplay= getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int Devicewidth= mDisplay.getWidth();
    int DeviceHeight= mDisplay.getHeight();
    for(int i=0; i<9 ; i++){
        //You can use different images here since i have only one I have used only one
        Bitmap oldBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap newBitmap = getResizedBitmap(oldBitmap, DeviceHeight/3, Devicewidth/3);
        img[i].setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
    }

}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}


}
```

Comment: That'll probably work, but I'm reluctant to use anything that involves Java code since the layout is static and therefore can be done entirely in xml.

Comment: @CalvinLi : The java code was just for safety purpose only, If you dont use the java code and only use the XML that i wrote here then also it still works. But remeber all the 9 images should be of same size. Please check it first

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GridView (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and set numColumns to 3. As for ImageView, you can play with ScaleType to see which one is best for your case, for example FIT_XY, etc.

Hope this helps.